# Fastest truncate in PHP - Benckmark

Tags: php, truncate

Im dealing with times across a non-sql database INTO a MySql db.
The data from the API im using comes with milliseconds in the format of:

```
2015-04-14T18:01:49.783
```

I have found several methods of removing everything after the period, but can not find a way to benchmark which is fastest.

This is working well:

```
$time="2015-04-14T18:01:49.783";
$timeArr= explode(".", $time);
$newTime= $timeArr[0];
```

But so is this:

```
$time = "2015-04-14T18:01:49.783";
$new_time = substr($time, 0, strpos($time, "."));
```

Also, I have found a few other methods..

The API im pulling from is between 40-80k people per "Clinic", and I have 20+ clinics.. So there are millions of them.. I guess im asking, in abstract "How do I benchmark my code against other code?" ALSO - the api will take its time to deliver, and never seems to execute in the same interval as the last time. Its hard to decern if the waiting time is from my code, or the api server..

Comment: Why don't you run a test of 50,000+ rows for both (just dummy data), and find out which is fastest?

Comment: you're probably only giong to save a second or two, which for 50,000 rows is essentially nothing. start benchmarking/choosing between them when you get into millions or billions of rows, and the savings can add up to minutes or hours.

Comment: In second example you are running function strpos() inside substr() function. Probably first example (with explode() ) is faster.

Comment: Sorry, need to elaborate.. The API im pulling from is between 40-80k people per "Clinic", and I have 20+ clinics.. So there are millions of them.. I guess I was asking a little more abstract "How do I benchmark my code against other code?" ALSO - the api will take its time to deliver, and its hard to decern if the waiting time is from my code, or the api server..

Comment: And more logging to your code so you have the insight you need to answer this.  Make it easier to discern.

Comment: Check out this question on how to benchmark your code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447778/php-microtime-benchmark-function-time-comparisons

Comment: The less you do, the faster it is. I ran a test on a small Ubuntu VM. On 10 million iterations, first method takes 5.59 seconds while the second one takes up 5.11 seconds - bear in mind, I ran the test just once. It's more than safe to assume that you are waiting for the other server to deliver data more than you are "wasting" time on selecting the fastest method, as you can see - the gains absolutely abysmal and not worth half a second of your time. Create code that works accurately - check your input, don't blindly trust the other server.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to run those.. I really do appreciate it. Can you tell me, how did you quickly create the dummy data to run that test?